# How can i save Text to Speech file as .wav/.mp3 format in External Storage

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm doing a sample Text to Speech application, in this my **requirement is to get a text from the user using EditText and save the input text as .wav/.mp3 format and stored in External Storage**. I used the following code for this process but i won't succeed.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save in Sdcard" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play the text file" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**TTS_AudioActivity.java**

```
public class TTS_AudioActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button store, play;
    EditText input;
    String speakTextTxt;
    private TextToSpeech mTts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        store = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        store.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                speakTextTxt = input.getText().toString();
                HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
                myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,
                        speakTextTxt);

                String exStoragePath = Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                File appTmpPath = new File(exStoragePath + "/sounds/");
                appTmpPath.mkdirs();
                String tempFilename = "tmpaudio.wav";
                String tempDestFile = appTmpPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
                        + tempFilename;

                mTts.synthesizeToFile(speakTextTxt, myHashRender, tempDestFile);

            }
        });

        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("/sdcard/sounds/tmpaudio.wav");
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                mMediaPlayer
                        .setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                            }
                        });

            }
        });

    }
}
```

in this, when i click Store button, the input text must be stored as .wav format, for this i used the code snippet form developer guide. Once it saved successfully, when i click Play button the save file must play. How can i achieve this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for the question. I am also having same requirement If you got it let me know or update with the answer.. Thanks..

Comment: Did you got answer for this?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to use function:

```
 public int synthesizeToFile (CharSequence text, Bundle params, File file, String utteranceId)
```

[API DOCUMENTATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29)

The code would be something like this:

```
    private void speakText(String text) {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // Can read and write the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;

    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        // Can only read the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        // Can't read or write
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }
    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "myData.mp3");
    int test = m_TTS.synthesizeToFile((CharSequence) text, null, file,
            "tts");
}
```

If everything works good the variable test must be 0.

**REMEMBER TO ADD PERMISSIONS TO YOUR MANIFEST:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile((Context) (this), new String[] {destFileName}, null, null);
```

Reconnect USB to your device.  Mine did not show the .wav files until I did.  Alternatively, use ASTRO File to view them.